# can we add multiple file paths for azure data explorer command in azure DevOps task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-explorer

can we add multiple file paths for azure data explorer command in azure DevOps task?
If yes, what is the order of execution?

I basically just want to point all the files (create table scripts, alter table scripts, functions scripts) in a single task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no predetermined order for the execution in file path match pattern.
I've added a feature to our backlog to support this, but for the time being you'll need to split the step to multiple steps.